# How to match regex single combine with multi groups same pattern in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have data in the following format:

```
n123a456ba789ba101112ba131415b
n124a12345ba78910ba101113b
n125a1234ba7891ba101114ba131415ba16171819b
```

n following with some data until a.

a is start field.

b is end field.

It has multiple fields a...b

I want to capture n data and data between a...b into array.
I tried with the following code but didn't work.

```
$var = "n123a456ba789ba101112ba131415b";

($n, @groups) = $var =~ /n(.+?)(?:a(.+?)b)+/;

print join(',', $n, @groups);
```

Comment: Change your regex to `/a([^b]+)b/g`: see code [here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lLLFIwVZBKc/QyDjRxNQsKdHcwjIp0dDA0NDQCEgbG5oYmiYpWXNpqOTpKDikF@WXFhRrAnVANNYp6CdqRMclxWprJumnW3MVFGXmlShk5WfmaajrqOsoIGuy/v8fAA)

Comment: I need n = 123 too.

Comment: But that doesn't follow your rule of `a...b` - what's the rule for that field?

Comment: n follow with some value until  a

Comment: Does `/(?|n([^a]+)(?=a)|a([^b]+)b)/g` work for you? See [this](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lLLFIwVZBKc/QyDjRxNQsKdHcwjIp0dDA0NDQCEgbG5oYmiYpWXNpqOTpKDikF@WXFhRrAnVANNYp6GvY1@RpRMclxmpratjbJmrWJAJ5SUBekqZ@ujVXQVFmXolCVn5mnoa6jrqOArIx1v//AwA)

Comment: Thankz outstanding work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/k7Uqwx/1)

```
/(?|n([^a]+)(?=a)|a([^b]+)b)/g
```

How it works:

- `(?|...)` branch reset - any subpatterns in such a group share the same number (this makes the capture groups share the same index if alternations exist)
- `n([^a]+)(?=a)|a([^b]+)b` match either of the following options:

  - `n([^a]+)(?=a)`

    - `n` matches `n` literally
    - `([^a]+)` captures any character except `a` one or more times into a capture group
    - `(?=a)` ensures the character `a` follows (positive lookahead) without consuming the character
  - `a([^b]+)b`

    - `a` matches `a` literally
    - `([^b]+)` captures any character except `b` one or more times into a capture group
    - `b` matches `b` literally

---

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lLLFIwVZBKc/QyDjRxNQsKdHcwjIp0dDA0NDQCEgbG5oYmiYpWXNpqOTpKDikF@WXFhRrAnVANNYp6GvY1@RpRMclxmpratjbJmrWJAJ5SUBekqZ@ujVXQVFmXolCVn5mnoa6jrqOArIx1v//AwA)

```
$var = "n123a456ba789ba101112ba131415b";
($n, @groups) = $var =~ /(?|n([^a]+)(?=a)|a([^b]+)b)/g;
print join(',', $n, @groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if the following code is comply with your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while( <DATA> ) {
    if( /^n(\d+)/ ) {
        my $n = $1;
        my @data = /a(\d+?)b/g;
        $hash{$n} = \@data;
    } 
}

say Dumper(\%hash);

__DATA__
n123a456ba789ba101112ba131415b
n124a12345ba78910ba101113b
n125a1234ba7891ba101114ba131415ba16171819b
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '123' => [
                     '456',
                     '789',
                     '101112',
                     '131415'
                   ],
          '125' => [
                     '1234',
                     '7891',
                     '101114',
                     '131415',
                     '16171819'
                   ],
          '124' => [
                     '12345',
                     '78910',
                     '101113'
                   ]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The target sample line seems fairly consistent.
This is a quick way to get it all in a single array, or the capture can be portioned via  `my ($n, @vals)` if needed.

```
$_ = "n123a456ba789ba101112ba131415b";
my @vals = /[na]([^ab]*)/g;
print join(',', @vals)
```

output

```
123,456,789,101112,131415
```

Comment: Well, then why not **my @vals =  /(\d+)/g;**?

Comment: You have stated **fairly consistent** -- for me it means that between **a** and **b** consistently will be digits.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0//functions/split.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @l = split /[nab]+/, $_;
    shift @l;
    dump@l;
}

__DATA__
n123a456ba789ba101112ba131415b
n124a12345ba78910ba101113b
n125a1234ba7891ba101114ba131415ba16171819b
```

**Output:**

```
(123, 456, 789, 101112, 131415)
(124, 12345, 78910, 101113)
(125, 1234, 7891, 101114, 131415, 16171819)
```